# how to call id with value <?php echo $ ?> in javascript

Tags: javascript, php

i have  div with id like this

```
<div id='alert<?php echo $row['no']?>'>
<b style='font-size:12px; color: red'>*DUPLICATE ID CUSTOMER</b>
</div>
```

and i need to call that id in javascript,

i try like this but the value not right

```
$("#alert<?php echo $row['no'] ?>").hide();
```

how to fix it

thankyou

Comment: If the JavaScript inside the loop that sets `$row`, it should work.

Comment: You need to show more context of the last snippet. Where does that code appear?

Comment: Please see [mcve]

Comment: if i used  the value from query php for instance  $("#alert35400").hide(); my code work, so i just need fix how to call the id value

Answer (score 0):

You need to include jQuery CDN

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script>
   $("#alert<?php echo $row['no'] ?>").hide();
</script>
```

Comment: i already put jquery cdn on header , i try your way also not working.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: share your code fully.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you have something like this:

```
foreach($result as $row){
  ?>
  <div id='alert<?php echo $row['no']?>'>
    <b style='font-size:12px; color: red'>*DUPLICATE ID CUSTOMER</b>
  </div>
  <script>$("#alert<?php echo $row['no'] ?>").hide();</script>
  <?php
}
```

Otherwise if the script-tag is outside the loop then it wount work.
Another solution would be to make a function let say hideAlert(div)
and do something like this:

```
<?php

foreach($result as $row){
  ?>
  <div onload="hideAlert(this)">
    <b style='font-size:12px; color: red'>*DUPLICATE ID CUSTOMER</b>
  </div>
  <?php
}
?>

<script>
  function hideAlert(div){
    div.hide();
  }
</script>
```

if you need the id to reference to it later you could just change the code like this:

```
foreach($result as $row){
  ?>
  <div onload="hideAlert(<?php echo $row['no']; ?>)">
    <b style='font-size:12px; color: red'>*DUPLICATE ID CUSTOMER</b>
  </div>
  <?php
}
?>

<script>
  function hideAlert(id){
    $(`#alert${id}`).hide();
  }
</script>
```

Keep in mind that I'm not an expert on jQuery soo I'm not really sure if this works but i hope it helps :)